# General solution to a tensor equation of this form?

Tags: general-relativity

Suppose I have some tensor equation which deals with rank-2 tensors of two variables $x,y$,

$$ \frac{\partial K^{ab}}{\partial x^k} g^{kc} = \frac{\partial g^{ab}}{\partial x^k} K^{kc} $$

This is obviously satisfied for $K^{ab} = g^{ab}$, but is there a way to solve the equation generally for $K^{ab}$?

Comment: This is not a tensor equation since you are using partial derivatives.

Comment: Not much extra info, but also $\lambda K^{ab} = g^{ab}$ are solutions for constants $\lambda$.